# How to set soap request to the payload mediator wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I call proxy service with SOAP request. I need to set this request directly payload factory mediator.Here is my SOAP request

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/soap_cm">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <bas:setMO>
   <query>
    <soap:baseObj>hhh</soap:baseObj>
    <soap:sc>ggggg</soap:sc>
   </query>
   <modi>
    <Attribute>
     <soap:mo>
      <soap:name>epsServiceProfile</soap:name>
      <soap:value>false</soap:value>
     </soap:mo>
     <operator>hhhh</operator>
    </Attribute>
   </modi>
  </bas:setMO>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your soap message name space prefix "bas" is not defined, so it is an invalid payload. You can use payload factory mediator for valid payload as below

```html
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
   <format>
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bas="http://test.com/bas" xmlns:soap="http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/soap_cm">
         <soapenv:Header />
         <soapenv:Body>
            <bas:setMO>
               <query>
                  <soap:baseObj>hhh</soap:baseObj>
                  <soap:sc>ggggg</soap:sc>
               </query>
               <modi>
                  <Attribute>
                     <soap:mo>
                        <soap:name>epsServiceProfile</soap:name>
                        <soap:value>false</soap:value>
                     </soap:mo>
                     <operator>hhhh</operator>
                  </Attribute>
               </modi>
            </bas:setMO>
         </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
   </format>
   <args />
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: Thank you Jenananthan. My requirement is when come request from the outside to the ESB I need to set that body inside the payload factory mediator.

Comment: when a request comes to esb it will be in message context, why do you need to set it again to message context via payload factory ?  you could elaborate your usecase more.